# Regular expression for dynamic replacement of the entered time

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help me make a regular expression (JS) with the following conditions

- enter a number in the field `<= 24`
- you can enter the decimal part separated by a dot (14.6, 3.4, 1, 3)
- the number must be rounded to one decimal place (23.45 -> 23.4, 1.42 -> 1.4, 1.27 -> 1.3)
- if the entered number is greater than 24, the number is replaced by the maximum (24)
- if the number is entered incorrectly, it is immediately replaced by correct

Here is my attempt to do something

```
/(^\d|1\d|2[0-4]|(^\d|1\d|2[0-3])\.\d)$/gm;
```

Comment: A regex cannot round numbers.

Comment: In what part of the world is 14.6 a valid time?  Does it mean 2:36pm?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer,  CIS counties

Comment: `if the number is entered incorrectly, it is immediately replaced by correct` How can you tell the correct number?

Comment: **First**, I'm from a CIS country, and `14.6` is only a valid time in a colloquial speech/chit-chat, and/or when people already know beforehand that there will be a piece of time information; normally we use `14:06`. **Second**, you're trying to do things with regex that cannot be done with regex (round, min/max); however, all this can easily be done with a very simple JavaScript program. Would you accept an answer that includes some JavaScript logic?